# python : automating web tasks

Tags: python

how can i automate web tasks with python

what i am trying to do is..

make the script open a forum thread url and post the text i wrote in the script
and multiply it with more urls and hopefully browsing them randomly and doing the same task

eg

```
urllist : example.txt
goto random url
do the task
repeat
```

can someone give me ideas to where to start and which programs i can use to entegrate with the browser?

i have basic knowledge in python i just need to know what information to learn to complete a script like this

im trying to improve myself

Comment: urllib, BeautifulSoup. Please don't write a spam bot.

Comment: i was just giving an example thanks for an honest answer thought

Comment: I recommend [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) as well. No need to integrate with the browser, but in case you want to see what is going on, visually, you can use [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html) with an ordinary browser (e.g. firefox)

Comment: Also, mechanize is a neat little library that will save you a lot of hassle, especially if you need to handle cookies and/or login forms.

Comment: Did you do any research before asking this question?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing that comes to mind for your goal is Selenium:
http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html

It can simulate human behavior (including login to site) and locate certain elements (then you can click/hover on them or download an image, for example). What's more - it can be used with PhantomJS (headless browser), so that you will not see the actual browser window. More info here: https://realpython.com/blog/python/headless-selenium-testing-with-python-and-phantomjs/

Selenium has built-in HTML parsing tools as well, so you will not need any extra libs like Beautiful Soup for parsing.